# How to make and statement on IF trigger SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement, triggers

I have a trigger and I have conditions in it, and I wanted to make something like this, but I can't manage to do it, I tried several things but none of them worked...

```
IF NEW.foo = OLD.foo AND NEW.bar = OLD.bar
THEN  
... 
RETURN NEW 
END IF; 
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION user_histo() RETURNS trigger AS $$
  BEGIN
                IF      TG_OP = 'INSERT'
                THEN
                        INSERT INTO table (attribute1, attribute2, attribute3, attribute4, attribute5, attribute6, attribute7)
                                VALUES (NEW.attribute1, NEW.attribute2, NEW.attribute3, NEW.attribute4, NEW.attribute5, NEW.attribute6, 'INSERT');
                        RETURN NEW;
                ELSIF   TG_OP = 'UPDATE'
                THEN
        IF (OLD.attribute2 = NEW.attribute2 AND  OLD.attribute3 = NEW.attribute3) // this is my problem
        THEN
                        INSERT INTO table (attribute1, attribute2, attribute3, attribute4, attribute5, attribute6, attribute7)
                                VALUES (OLD.attribute1, OLD.attribute2, OLD.attribute3, OLD.attribute4, OLD.attribute5, OLD.attribute6, 'UPDATE');
                        INSERT INTO table (attribute1, attribute2, attribute3, attribute4, attribute5, attribute6, attribute7)
                                VALUES (NEW.attribute1, NEW.attribute2, NEW.attribute3, NEW.attribute4, NEW.attribute5, NEW.attribute6, 'INSERT');
        RETURN NEW;
        ELSE
        RETURN NULL;
        END IF;
        END IF;
        END;

$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_table AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON table
        FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE user_histo();
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question? Are you getting an error? The wrong behavior?

Comment: I don't really get errors, but it just don't work

Comment: AFTER INSERT ON table, you trigger a new INSERT ON table ... this will lead to an infinite loop, won't it ?

Comment: the condition is working well, see the test in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yEao4B_N). Your problem is somewhere else...

Comment: My problem was about IF ELSE RETURN, nothing to do about the IF AND component. Thank you very much !